# Calling REST api to get images

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js

I am calling REST api from my Vue code as below

```
let file = BASEURL + 'download/' + docId;

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + TOKEN);
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

fetch(file, { headers })
.then(response => {return response.data})
```

The data expected is a base64 image, but I get junk data returned.
What am I missing?

When I look at the 'Network' tab in dev tools I get

ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC

ÿÛC

ÿÀX "ÿÄ ÿÄB!1AQ"a2q#BR¡±ÁÑ3b$Cráðñ%4S²ÿÄÿÄ5!1"AQ2aq#¡B±ÁÑ3áðñR$ÿÚ?\èÍk~£C+.cµHIíçrI1ø #dcni#ÒV

Comment: Depends what you mean by "junk" - can you show an example of what the API returns? Can you sure the server API code?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But I know the API works fine without authorization in a download attribute. Since I need to authorize, I have to do it in javascript

Comment: @user2837961 if you can't sure code then can you explain what you mean by "junk", so you get _something_ from the server? What do you get?

Comment: what does the `Content-Type` header say in the Network tab? The data needs to be parsed in the relevant format e.g. `response.text()`

Comment: Content-Type in Response Headers is application/octet-stream

Comment: @user2837961 that seems incorrect, it should probably be application/json or text/plain. You can try making the request with the Accept header with one of those values.

Comment: @James For some reason the Content-Type is still application/octet-stream in the response headers. Please see the question as to how I have added the header

Comment: @user2837961 well that explains why you get "junk", its trying to display binary content as ASCII. As suggested, that does appear to be odd if the APIs purpose is to return a base64 string, you could try determine if the API supports [content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) and pass an `Accept` header as say `text/plain` then handle at the client with `response.text()`.

Comment: It is strange because if I hardcode a url say http://localhost:3000/download/66, it still says application/octet-stream but when putting this url in my browser, it downloads the file

Comment: @user2837961 sorry.... you say "downloads the file", if it's a file this is supposed to be downloading then that makes perfect sense (it's not a raw base64 string in that case). It appears it's downloading a file with a base64 string inside? In that case, on the client you would need to use `response.blob()`

Comment: @James downloads a jpg file

Comment: @user2837961 makes sense, see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue appears to be the fact that the server is using a general MIME type to return the file i.e. `application/octet-stream`, as opposed to the correct MIME type for the particular image, which would be `image/jpg`. This would explain why the browser is unable to render the image and instead you get what you deem "junk" (it's really just an ASCII representation of the binary content of the image).

Given it's a file, and therefore a stream, you can you can use the [blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob) function on the response object to read the data. There is actually a good [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Examples) of how to download an image using the Fetch API and render it into an image which you should be able to tweak to suit your needs:

```
const image = document.querySelector('.my-image');
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function(blob) {
  const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  image.src = objectURL;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting the raw binary response.

Seeing that you try to access the data property, I assume that the response format is a JSON string with a data property that is a base64 string representing an image.

```
fetch(file, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + TOKEN,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
}) // Get data from endpoint
.then(response => response.json()) // Parse response as JSON
.then(response => response.data) // Get data property from response object
```

If the whole response is a base64 string instead of an JSON object with a base64 string you can do the following.

```
fetch(file, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + TOKEN,
        'Accept': 'plain/text'
    }
}) // Get data from endpoint
.then(response => response.text()) // Parse response as plain text
```

Also as seen above you need to tell the server what response format you expect using the Accept header.

Comment: @James, ah that's weird indeed since the dev tools itself handles the parsing and presentation in that case itself already :/